# Cross origin error when trying to reference external JS file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a react app (runs with webpack) with a file within it that I want to access externally from a script tag.

I have inserted the script-tag into the external site; it has a src which points towards the JS file where I am tying to iFrame some content. I am inserting the script-tag because this is how this works with shopify.

My script tag, inserted into an external site looks like this (referencing my JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" 
src="https://57584930.ngrok.io/Scripts/javascript.js? 
shop=daleandkiko.myshopify.com"></script>
```

This is hopefully going to point towards my js file, which just for testing purposes I am trying to iframe the google page:

```
function prepareFrame() {
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "http://google.com/");
ifrm.style.width = "640px";
ifrm.style.height = "480px";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

The file structure is this:

Client
      / Scripts
            / javascript.js

When I hit this endpoint is directs to the react app anyway, as the normal 
https://57584930.ngrok.io URL does, so I'm a bit lost here, Am i referencing the file correctly?

Within the external site I get this error:

(index):73 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://57584930.ngrok.io/Scripts/javascript.js?shop=daleandkiko.myshopify.com with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Is this how it works or is this different because it's a create-react-app?

Comment: When I try to visit the ngrok.io url you've provided, I get an HTML page stating "Tunnel 57584930.ngrok.io not found".

Comment: Sorry Kevin I deliberately provided a false one

Comment: the real url would be https://633bf6e9.ngrok.io/Scripts/javascript.js... The other stuff on the end shopify add on when its loaded

Comment: When I visit that link, I don't get JavaScript.  I get a full webpage.  I doesn't make sense to try to load a full webpage as a script.

Comment: This is what I don't understand, the webpage is what's loaded as my react app, I dont have a server on it its run as webpack, so I guess im going about it the wrong way? should I be used a node server instead?

Comment: For some reason accessing the react app using any extra url added onto the starting ngrol url will just send the visitor to the main view

Comment: I would definitely recommend using a node server instead.  Webpack's server is only intended for development, not production.

Comment: Okay, when I tried sending the link to the node server It said GET could not be found, perhaps I need to redirect to the url properly using a app.post( '/script/javascript) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186012/discussion-between-sparlarva-and-kevin628).